# Determine loading state of base map layers in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, layers, loading

What is the JavaScript command to know the loading state of the current layer? I'd like to know is the layer is loading, with 'true' or 'false', when the page loads or when I move the map.

This example is using Leaflet Basemaps control (https://github.com/consbio/Leaflet.Basemaps).

```
  var map = L.map("map").setView([44.07, -118.78], 5);

    var basemaps = [
        L.tileLayer("//stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner-lite/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
            attribution:
                'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
            subdomains: "abcd",
            maxZoom: 20,
            minZoom: 0,
            label: "Toner Lite"
        }),
        L.tileLayer("//stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
            attribution:
                'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
            subdomains: "abcd",
            maxZoom: 20,
            minZoom: 0,
            label: "Toner"
        }),
        L.tileLayer("//stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
            attribution:
                'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
            subdomains: "abcd",
            maxZoom: 16,
            minZoom: 1,
            label: "Watercolor"
        })
    ];

    map.addControl(
        L.control.basemaps({
            basemaps: basemaps,
            tileX: 0,
            tileY: 0,
            tileZ: 1
        })
    );
```

So far I tried:

```
basemaps.on('tileload', function (event) {
   console.log('loading');
    });
```

This example is here :

https://consbio.github.io/Leaflet.Basemaps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`basemaps` is an JS array of layers and as such has no event processing methods. You have to iterate through layers array and catch tile loading events of each layer. `loading` event is fired when the layer starts loading tiles, and `load` event is fired when layer loaded all visible tiles.

In your case code for catching event could look something like this (should be inserted immediately after `basemaps` array definition):

```
basemaps.forEach(function(basemap) {
  basemap.on('loading', function(evt) {
    console.log('load start:', evt.target.options.label);
  });
  basemap.on('load', function(evt) {
    console.log('load end:', evt.target.options.label);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you as usual. It's working!

Now everyone can include Leaflet Spin in their script ( https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.Spin )
and insert and remove a spin with map.spin(true); and map.spin(false); in the events functions, instead of the console logs.